# OpenCV-Python : Issue with getting frame rate of video

Tags: python, opencv, video, frame-rate

I recorded a short video clip using my laptop camera. My laptop is Acer Aspire 4755G.
I wanted to check the fps of the video using OpenCV Python. But the result I got was "1000". Shouldn't it be somewhere around 30 or something? Below is my code.

PS. I got some error when trying to get fps directly from webcam.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.avi')
print cap.get(5)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(150) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I opened the video in Cheese (I'm using Ubuntu 12.04) and checked under Properties. It said FRAME RATE : 25 frames per second Also, I tried replacing cap.get(5) with cap.get(7) so as to get info about the total no. of frames in the video file. It returned 16891. The video is only 16 secs long so that would come to roughly 100 fps. Is it a bug in OpenCV? Or is there something wrong in my code? I'm using OpenCV 2.4.9 which is the latest at the moment i presume. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can try `cv2.VideoCapture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, <value>)` and `cv2.VideoCapture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)` to set and get FPS of the video. See http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get

Comment: @Vipul I tried the code you mentioned but it gave an error that said AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'get'.
I also tried the print cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
but got the same result ie 1000

Comment: cv2.VideoCapture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) for Opencv 3.4.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your AVI file -- the framerate is defined in the header ([see here](http://www.fastgraph.com/help/avi_header_format.html)).  I just tried your code on a video I had lying around and it gave me 59.9400599401 (it was from a 60fps GoPro).  When I opened it up in a hex editor, sure enough bits 20-52 give 16683, or 1/59.9... in microseconds.

Likely the AVI you created/have didn't have that property set correctly.

One thing you can do is to [convert the file with avconv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370692/how-to-change-the-framerate-of-a-video-without-reencoding) to something with a known framerate.  If you're on windows, I'm sure there's a utility, but I don't know one off the top of my head.

Comment: The video file was made using Cheese in Ubuntu 12.04. The default file extension is .webm but I changed that to .avi while saving. Could that be the reason?
I recorded another video (this time using OpenCV itself) and checked its framerate using the above program. This time it showed 20fps (I verified that using Totem Movie Player).

Also, How do I check bits in the header? I installed Bless Hex Editor and opened the avi file but couldn't identify the bits.

Comment: I just tried saving/renaming as a .avi in Cheese and it only seems to change the name, not the actual filetype.  If you open it up in a hex editor the header is different (webm header looks like) and avconv confirms it is webm (`avconv -i file.avi`).  To check the header in a real AVI, it is a 32-bit unsigned integer starting at bit 20.  But overall, the answer to your question is, you didn't have an AVI file, so the header's framerate number wasn't there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I know where is bit 20? I only see a lot of numbers in hex editor.